# Where should i put IInAppBillingService.aidl file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing

Hi i have added IInAppBillingService.aidl file to ../main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/ directory but no java file generated. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer. just in case this happens someone else, i am writing the answer. You just need to sync files with sync tool of gradle.